ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH, chromedriver_autoinstaller.install
Trying to use chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() but getting the ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/e/reports_automation/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/__init__.py", line 21, in install
    chromedriver_filepath = utils.download_chromedriver(path, no_ssl)
  File "/home/e/reports_automation/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 269, in download_chromedriver
    chrome_version = get_chrome_version()
  File "/home/e/reports_automation/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 140, in get_chrome_version
    path = get_linux_executable_path()
  File "/home/e/reports_automation/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 196, in get_linux_executable_path
    raise ValueError("No chrome executable found on PATH")
ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH


Assuming your Chrome executable is in the default location for your operating system (or on your System PATH), this should be enough with the latest version of Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...
driver.quit()

But if Chrome is not located in the default location, you must specify where it is.
For example, in the script below, the user supplies the locations for chromedriver and the Chrome binary:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "PATH_TO_BINARY.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()


As of Selenium 4.6, they've added SeleniumManager that automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the desired browser and version for you. You can get rid of any other DriverManager and related code you are using.
The minimum required code to start the browser now is
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

